# Append Material UI Button On Scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, material-ui

I am using React and Material UI to build a chrome extension. This extension aims to append a button to a div class every time the user scrolls (the div class only appears when the user scrolls). However, I keep getting an `Uncaught Error: Minified React error #321;` because of how I am using my hooks. How can I add a hook once a user scrolls?

Windows On Scroll Code:

```
    $(window).on("load", function() {
  // var button = RecipeReviewCard();
  // console.log('i am the button', button);
  function injectButton() {
   var className = ".product-tile__badges";

   $(className).append(RecipeReviewCard());

   $('.dropdown1').mouseenter(function () {
     var dropDownMenu = $(this).children().eq(1);
     dropDownMenu.css('display', 'block');
   });

   // add event listener to hide dropdown on mouse leave
   $('.dropdown1').mouseleave(function () {
     var dropDownMenu = $(this).children().eq(1);
     dropDownMenu.css('display', 'none');
        });
 }
  console.log(RecipeReviewCard());
  // $(window).scroll(injectButton);
   });
```

Material UI hook code:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    maxWidth: 345,
  },
  media: {
    height: 0,
    paddingTop: '56.25%', // 16:9
  },
  expand: {
    transform: 'rotate(0deg)',
    marginLeft: 'auto',
    transition: theme.transitions.create('transform', {
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.shortest,
    }),
  },
  expandOpen: {
    transform: 'rotate(180deg)',
  },
  avatar: {
    backgroundColor: red[500],
  },
}));

export default function RecipeReviewCard() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(false); // First thing is the value and the second sets the value

  const handleExpandClick = () => {
    setExpanded(!expanded);
  };

  return (
    <Card className={classes.root}>
      <CardHeader
        avatar={
          <Avatar aria-label="recipe" className={classes.avatar}>
            R
          </Avatar>
        }
        action={
          <IconButton aria-label="settings">
            <MoreVertIcon />
          </IconButton>
        }
        title="Shrimp and Chorizo Paella"
        subheader="September 14, 2016"
      />
      <CardMedia
        className={classes.media}
        image="/static/images/cards/paella.jpg"
        title="Paella dish"
      />
      <CardContent>
        <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
          This impressive paella is a perfect party dish and a fun meal to cook together with your
          guests. Add 1 cup of frozen peas along with the mussels, if you like.
        </Typography>
      </CardContent>
      <CardActions disableSpacing>
        <IconButton aria-label="add to favorites">
          <FavoriteIcon />
        </IconButton>
        <IconButton aria-label="share">
          <ShareIcon />
        </IconButton>
        <IconButton
          className={clsx(classes.expand, {
            [classes.expandOpen]: expanded,
          })}
          onClick={handleExpandClick}
          aria-expanded={expanded}
          aria-label="show more"
        >
          <ExpandMoreIcon />
        </IconButton>
      </CardActions>
      <Collapse in={expanded} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
        <CardContent>
          <Typography paragraph>Method:</Typography>
          <Typography paragraph>
            Heat 1/2 cup of the broth in a pot until simmering, add saffron and set aside for 10
            minutes.
          </Typography>
          <Typography paragraph>
            Heat oil in a (14- to 16-inch) paella pan or a large, deep skillet over medium-high
            heat. Add chicken, shrimp and chorizo, and cook, stirring occasionally until lightly
            browned, 6 to 8 minutes. Transfer shrimp to a large plate and set aside, leaving chicken
            and chorizo in the pan. Add pimentón, bay leaves, garlic, tomatoes, onion, salt and
            pepper, and cook, stirring often until thickened and fragrant, about 10 minutes. Add
            saffron broth and remaining 4 1/2 cups chicken broth; bring to a boil.
          </Typography>
          <Typography paragraph>
            Add rice and stir very gently to distribute. Top with artichokes and peppers, and cook
            without stirring, until most of the liquid is absorbed, 15 to 18 minutes. Reduce heat to
            medium-low, add reserved shrimp and mussels, tucking them down into the rice, and cook
            again without stirring, until mussels have opened and rice is just tender, 5 to 7
            minutes more. (Discard any mussels that don’t open.)
          </Typography>
          <Typography>
            Set aside off of the heat to let rest for 10 minutes, and then serve.
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </Collapse>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

Comment: Why do you use ReactJS + JQuery instead of just ReactJS?

Comment: No specific reason. I am new to JS, and I was familiar with the jQuery function.